# Tranform XML, Ingore some element, if in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement where I need to transform XML via XSLT so that some elements can be ignored. For example, I have below XML to convert.

```
<ItemList>
    <Item ItemID ="Itemid" Status="status">
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID ="1234" Status="2000">
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID ="4567" Status="3000">
    </Item>
</ItemList>
```

And I have written XSLT like this.

```
<xsl:template match = "/">
        <ItemList>
            <xsl:for-each select = "/ItemList/Item">
                <xsl:element name = "{name()}">
                    <xsl:attribute name = "ItemID">
                        <xsl:value-of select = "@ItemID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:element name = "PrimaryInformation">
                        <xsl:attribute name = "Status">
                            <xsl:value-of select = "@Status"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ItemList>
    </xsl:template>
```

And I want output like as below.

```
<ItemList>
    <Item ItemID="1234">
        <PrimaryInformation Status="2000"/>
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID="4567">
        <PrimaryInformation Status="3000"/>
    </Item>
</ItemList>
```

So basically I want to ignore the first element where itemid = ItemId. So can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a condition, in square brackets, to your select expression

```
<xsl:for-each select = "/ItemList/Item[@ItemID != 'Itemid']">
```

Or this...

```
<xsl:for-each select = "/ItemList/Item[not(@ItemID = 'Itemid')]">
```

There is a difference between the two, in that the first one will ignore `Item` records which have no `ItemID` attributes, but the second would select them.

Note: As an aside, you can simplify the creation of the `PrimaryInformation` element to just this, which makes use of Attribute Value Templates to create its `Status` attribute.

```
<PrimaryInformation Status="{@Status}" />
```